# SQL Server - convert number to time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have one field storing time as integer value.
I want to convert integer to time as follows.

```
IntegerValue    TimeValue
-------------------------
1               00:01 AM
11              00:11 AM
123             01:23 AM
541             05:41 AM
1317            13:17 PM
```

Please reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR, coulmn / 100) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, column% 100),2)
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,
It is almost similar to @Mukund answer

```
SELECT c AS IntegerValue
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, c / 100) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, c % 100), 2) AS TimeValue
FROM (
    VALUES (1)
        ,(11)
        ,(123)
        ,(541)
        ,(1317)
    ) t(c)
```